# unsorted_set hashing error

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

I recently started to make a game with a friend, but we now encountered a problem with unsorted lists. I checked this site and other forums, but nothing seems to work.

Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/nx8sf6T2

And the compiler error: http://pastebin.com/fdQ7B0Dx

(And for compiling I use "clang++ -std=c++11 main3D.cpp", in case anyone is wondering)

Comment: possibly `struct hash<point>` definition should preceed `std::unordered_set<point> points;` instantiation

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hash<point>` must be known at the time of instantiation of `std::unordered_set<point>`, and that requires `point` to be known before `hash<point>`:

```
struct point
{
    // contents...
};

namespace std
{
        template<>
        struct hash<point>
        {
                // contents...
        };
}  

struct line
{
        std::unordered_set<point> points;
        // contents...
};

namespace std
{
        template<>
        struct hash<line>
        {
                // contents...
        };
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cae413f58623645d)

Comment: Thank you it worked :D I can't belive it was that obvious and I didn't notice it before...

Comment: @Slava - As a warning, do not insult people leaving good answers and trying to help others here.